# Javascript won't update DOM on what appears to be recent Items

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I'm using 100% pure javascript, tried Jquery but it didn't help. Code not working in FF/Chrome/Safari.

I have built Edit-In-Place functionality where when the user clicks "Edit" (calling external function with onclick - passing in item_id) -- a string of text is hidden to reveal an input with the same string of text in it. (by changing classes) "Edit" is also replaced by "Save". When done editing the string - the user clicks save, and everything reverts back to normal.

AJAX is processing all the updates - but commenting out the AJAX block does not fix it.

I am loading a stream of these objects. The javascript *works* for all of them - but only updates the DOM, visually anyway for what *appears* is items before the last 24 hours. The blocks themselves are identical. That is - items that have been added within the last 18-26 hours when I click "Edit", do nothing. BUT if I alert out the class of the element I want to edit it says "editing" (as opposed to "saved") like it is working. (see below) Although this change is never reflected in inspect element.

***Code on Page***

```
<input type="text" class="input_field" id="input_254" value="Foo" onkeydown="javascript: if (event.keyCode == 13) { update(254); }" style="display: none; ">
<span class="user_links" id="display_269" style="display:none;">Foo</span> //hidden span that holds the value and acts at the check
<span id="edit_state_269" class="saved" style="display: none;">Foo</span>
<span onclick="update(269)" id="edit_269">Edit</span>
```

***External Javascript***

```
function update(item_id) {

var links_span = document.getElementById('display_' + item_id);
var input_span = document.getElementById('input_' + item_id);
var string_old = document.getElementById('edit_state_' + item_id).innerHTML;
var state_check = document.getElementById('edit_state_' + item_id);
var edit_button = document.getElementById('edit_' + item_id);

if (state_check.getAttribute('class') == 'saved') {

    // Hide the links display list and show the input field
    links_span.style.display = 'none';
    input_span.style.display = 'inline';

    // Change the Edit button text and state_check
    edit_button.innerHTML = 'Save';
    state_check.setAttribute('class','editing');

    //alert(state_check.getAttribute('class')); // this alerts "editing" although in DOM it is still "saved" on the blocks that are the problem
```

If any more details would be helpful - I will provide them.

It is a devil of a problem - with no obvious solution. Would really appreciate any direction you can give!

Comment: there are mixed number in your html - 254 and 269

Comment: The best help I have time to give right now is this - if I understand your requirements, your code is way off. I suggest looking into something pre-built. Since you mentioned jQuery in your post, I would suggest starting here: How to use: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable. Demos: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. As usual it's the little things. The first few blocks were being loaded on page load - and then hidden as the user navigated resulting in duplicate IDs. Javascript naturally selected the one higher on the page - the one that was hidden.